# Android Usb Communication Issue

Tags: android, mobile, usb

I am developing an android app that communicate via usb port. When open the app, MainActivity request usb permission. if I open app after 10 seconds from plug usb device, app recorgnize usb device correctly. but after I plug usb device if I open app immediately, app does not recorgnize usb device. how to solve this issue?

When I plugin and start the app immediately, usb device is not detected.
when I close the app and restart in, but leave the plug connected, the app has usb permission by default.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my app. It's called ez dash. It worked great with android 12 but with the release  of 13 it now behaves as you described.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).